# How to Integrate jQuery with React js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I badly need jQuery Api's, but the thing is I have use that api with React js. I am just confusing my React js Lifecycles.
Additional Info I am creating view counter for different div. In my Point of View I badly need jQuery api's to take care the height, ScrollTop..
The following code will output Undefined

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var NewsDetail = require('./news-details');
var $ = require('jquery');


module.exports = React.createClass({
    getInitialState:function () {

      return{
          news:[
              {

              {
                  id:"5",
                  data:"I probably am using the wrong I probably am using the wrong terminology here but this is what I'm trying to do. I want to create a map with a value terminology here but this is what I'm trying to do. I want to create a map with a value for each key and a value for each key's object. S"
              },
              {
                  id:"6",
                  data:"I probably am using the wrong I probably am using the wrong terminology here but this is what I'm trying to do. I want to create a map with a value I probably am using the wrong terminology here but this is what I'm trying to do. I want to create a map with a value I probably am using the wrong terminology here but this is what I'm trying to do. I want to create a map with a value terminology here but this is what I'm trying to do. I want to create a map with a value for each key and a value for each key's object. S"
              },
              {
                  id:"7",
                  data:"I probably am using the wrong terminology here but this is what I'm trying to do. I want to create a map with a value I probably am using the wrong terminology here but this is what I'm trying to do. I want to create a map with a value I probably am using the wrong terminology here but this is what I'm trying to do. I want to create a map with a value for each key and a value for each key's object. S"
              },
              {
                  id:"8",
                  data:"I probably am using the wrong I probably am using the wrong terminology here but this is what I'm trying to do. I want to create a map with a value terminology here but this is what I'm trying to do. I want to create a map with a value for each key and a value for each key's object. S"
              },
              {
                  id:"9",
                  data:"I probably am using the wrong I probably am using the wrong terminology here but this is what I'm trying to do. I want to create a map with a value I probably am using the wrong terminology here but this is what I'm trying to do. I want to create a map with a value I probably am using the wrong terminology here but this is what I'm trying to do. I want to create a map with a value terminology here but this is what I'm trying to do. I want to create a map with a value for each key and a value for each key's object. S"
              },

          ],
          top:0,
          height:null
      }
    },
    componentWillMount:function () {

    },
    componentDidUpdate:function () {

        var height = $('#newscontainer').height();
        alert(height)//udefined

    },
    render:function () {

      var newsdata = this.state.news.map(function (newss) {

          return(<NewsDetail key={newss.id} {...newss}/>)
      });
        return(
            <div className="newscontanier" id="newscontanier">{newsdata}</div>
        )



    }

})
```

Comment: Why do you need jQuery? If you are just getting the height of the element, you can do that without jQuery.

Comment: var height = $('#newscontainer').height(); is selecting the wrong id, according to your DOM. ... id="newscontanier"

Comment: your id is misspelled in your render function.

Comment: Ya! I Google a Lot But Nothing's worked for Pls could refer any link ...

Comment: I agree with @NicholasRobinson ... I don't see why you need jQuery in this situation.

Comment: @ray  Pls could you post the solution in the answer

Comment: @Nane How about vanilla JavaScript: `document.getElementById('newscontanier').offsetHeight`

Comment: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typo `newscontanier`. Nonetheless you can do this like

```
<div ref={elem => this.elem = elem} className="newscontanier" id="newscontanier">{newsdata}</div>
```

and then you can find dom element

```
this.elem.getDOMNode();
```

Comment: getDOMNode is [deprecated](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#dom-node-refs)

Comment: @ray I didn't know it. anyway you can get DOM node from `this.elem`